# Determine the centre/center of a circle using multiple points

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, algorithm, geometry, 2d

I was wondering if somebody could help me, I can do it on pen and paper using a compass, but can't do it in Actionscript 3.

As the title says, essentially I need to find the centre of a circle using multiple points from the radius.

Comment: It's pretty much the same as how you would do it in math class, except the Y-axis is inverted.

Comment: Sadly I didn't do maths to a high level, and yes I do have the radius.

Comment: I thought about trying to use a matrix, but most the AS things I have seen are transformation matrixes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want the [Equation for a Circle from 3 Points](https://web.archive.org/web/20120414124330/http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/%7Epbourke//geometry/circlefrom3/). Dr. Math also has [some nice explanations](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224041229/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/sets/select/dm_center_circle.html) on your question.

**Edit**: I've implemented this in JavaScript + SVG; you can see the interactive result on my website:
http://phrogz.net/SVG/3-point-circle.xhtml

Here's the relevant code (I've created a `Point` class like in ActionScript with `.x` and `.y` properties):

```
function findCircleCenter(p1,p2,p3){
  var d2  = p2.x*p2.x + p2.y*p2.y;
  var bc  = (p1.x*p1.x + p1.y*p1.y - d2) / 2;
  var cd  = (d2 - p3.x*p3.x - p3.y*p3.y) / 2;
  var det = (p1.x-p2.x) * (p2.y-p3.y) - (p2.x-p3.x) * (p1.y-p2.y);
  if (Math.abs(det) > 1e-10) return new Point(
    (bc * (p2.y-p3.y) - cd * (p1.y-p2.y)) / det,
    ((p1.x-p2.x) * cd - (p2.x-p3.x) * bc) / det
  );
}
```

**Edit 2**: For fun, instead of 3 points defining one circle, how about 6 points defining 20? :)
http://phrogz.net/SVG/3-point-circle2.xhtml

Comment: Thanks for this, I had seen the mathforum.org stuff before when I googled it.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have radius, and three points around the circumference which are arbitrarily spaced.

Comment: @S1syphus Nevermind, I've added my own example. Note that 3 points define a circle, so the radius that you already 'know' is irrelevant and might be in conflict.

Comment: +1 for the demo. Love to drag one point between the other 2 :-)